Estimation of when to prefer ultrafast silicon diodes over silicon Schottky diodes
When comparing "ultrafast" silicon diodes (those with usual recovery times given as either 50 or 75 ns) to silicon Schottky diodes at the same blocking voltage and average current rating, one notices that Schottky diodes have a lot more junction capacitance, but no reverse recovery issues.
I was wondering if ultrafast silicon diodes would be less lossy when low currents were concerned, because both conduction losses and reverse recovery losses would become less important. I made a small loss estimation based on the three (I think) most important loss mechanisms in each switching period:



Loss contribution
Energy estimate per switching period




conduction loss
\$I_\text f \cdot V_\text f \cdot t_\text f\$


capacitive loss
\$\frac{1}{2} \cdot C_\text J \cdot V_\text{rev}^2\$


reverse recovery loss
\$I_\text f \cdot t_\text{rr} \cdot V_\text{rev}\$



These are very crude "rectangular integral" estimations, so they will mainly give order of magnitude figures. Based on this I indeed found, that for some lower current applications silicon ultrafast diodes would be better, even in hard switched applications.
I am rather uncertain about that last term. It assumes that the reverse recovery charge can be estimated as the forward current times the reverse recovery time.
Question:
Does it not (substantially) matter for reverse recovery what the reverse recovery current will be? It can be much larger than the forward current, because it is not limited by a series inductor (thinking of a boost converter circuit for example.)
If so, what would be a better estimator for the reverse recovery loss energy based on usual datasheet figures?

Not related to your question, but note that Schottky diodes can have enough reverse leakage at high temperatures to impact overall efficiency.

There's more to it in Trr snap-off  https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+recovery+loss+energy  (see ST.com et al )

@D.A.S. I think I've seen this document, but I don't know how to estimate the reverse current $I_{RM}$ from their sketch. However, I had read several times in random locations, that it is approximately the same as the forward current because the charge to be evacuated is also depending on the forward current. Would you agree on a coarse basis?

@tobalt The peak reverse recovery current is definitely not approximately the same as the forward current--I've run that test for my workplace (a semiconductor manufacturer) and the peak reverse current is much more related to the current slew rate.

@Hearth I see, so this implies that the recovery time is indeed sort of constant and the recovery charge increases when the diode is turned off harder? (I am merely looking to get the generic behavior correct to make proper order of magnitude estimations)

@tobalt Some of the diodes I've tested showed sort-of-constant recovery time, but not many of them. The recovery charge is supposedly closer to constant in the literature, but that's also not really what I observed. Really, it's all sort of messy and doesn't match the ideal situation very well. || Somewhat interestingly, another thing I observed that I haven't seen reported in the literature (because no one cares about SiC pn diodes) is that SiC pn diodes appear to have extremely short recovery time, shorter than I could measure with my setup. And yes, they were pn diodes, not schottkys.

@Hearth Could one say, that the recovery charge is at least/most some value? Perhaps, does the formula I used in the question represent some kind of minimum value, but the actual value could be higher if dI/dt is very high? And how much higher? As I said, I am mainly trying to get a ballpark estimate to get a feeling for whether Si ultrafast are ever worth it at sub-200V applications.. So if you have any idea of such approximate upper/lower bounds, that would suffice as an answer i guess.

dV/dt depends on Q and dC/dt and dI/dt depends on what? parasitic L?

The last one is in error: it should be IRR, not IF.  To the extent these are proportionate (which is roughly true in most operating conditions), that's still the right sort of idea though.  Note that, in this case, tRR must refer to the falling edge, not the full (IF < 0) recovery transient; this is related to the total tRR as-published when taking into account softness factor (tRR = ta + tb, and tb/ta = s).
The second one isn't likely to be correct "within an order of magnitude": because C varies so much, and because switch voltage is so much higher than diode (reverse) voltage at the same time, power dissipation is heavily weighted towards C(V) at low V.  The proportion is right (depends on capacitance) -- but what capacitance, or when, is the question.  I would suggest doing some simulations to find typical values; perhaps it can be calculated symbolically from the m-grading equation as well.
Note these may also assume low relative loop inductance, which isn't a great assumption these days.  That mainly changes where the power is dissipated; a very fast turn-on and relatively slow diode turn-off (or weighty schottky junction) will put more energy into that inductance, and thus whatever's snubbing it.
A related measure is the inductive or current-ramp equivalent capacitance.  In the same way we can express Coss or Cj in terms of an RC equivalent, or energy equivalent, we can calculate the time and thus equivalent capacitance for a ramp waveform.  This isn't usually documented in datasheets (honestly, I've never seen it), but simply by the same process, we can come up with other equivalents.  Values calculated in this way tend to be much larger: one worksheet I have, compares Coss effective equivalent of a MOSFET: RC equivalent, 491pF (calculated from curve fit; datasheet value: 391pF), E equivalent 216pF, ramp equivalent 562pF, and constant-current equivalent a whopping 792pF.
My experience has been, schottky are good almost everywhere in general power switching applications, and less preferred where leakage, peak/surge ratings/performance, low capacitance, and low cost (at high voltages where SiC is applicable) are important.  And of course, neither when synchronous rectification is available.
